# Error incorrect syntax near keyword 'Delete' in SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

My SP is throwing error where I am trying to delete some entries from the tables. To be in safe side I got `IF EXISTS` and under it I have the delete statement but I am getting this error

`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DELETE'.`

Delete stmt

```
IF EXISTS (DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id IN ((SELECT ids FROM @tranId)));
```

I am not sure if the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: _"I am not sure if the syntax is incorrect"_ I'm sure it is not if i look at the error xD

Comment: You can't use `DELETE` in `EXISTS`, you have to use `SELECT`. `EXISTS` takes a subquery that might return rows, if there is at least one row then it returns `TRUE`.

Comment: I was also thinking if it is correct to Delete inside IF condition.

Comment: Looks like I cannot use IF Exists with Delete. Thanks Tim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `IF` is unnecessary, as are the extra parentheses:

```
DELETE FROM ESG.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANS_MDATA
    WHERE DOCUMENT_SET_TRANS_MDATA.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION_ID IN (SELECT ids FROM @tranId);

DELETE FROM ESG.DOCUMENT_TRANSACTION
    WHERE DOCUMENT_TRANSACTION.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION_ID IN (SELECT ids FROM @tranId);

DELETE FROM ESG.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION
    WHERE DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION_ID IN (SELECT ids FROM @tranId);
```

Comment: Correct, there is no need for IF EXISTS since the rows wont be deleted if they are not there and it won't throw an error.